# Adding html text to Word using Interop

Tags: html, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to add some HTML formatted text to Word using Office Interop. My code looks like this:

```
Clipboard.SetText(notes, TextDataFormat.Html);
pgCriteria.Range.Paste();
```

but it's throwing a Command Failed exception. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending several hours the solutions is to use this excellent class
http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/pages/sample-code-html-clipboard.aspx

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Windows 7 and Word 2007:

```
public static void pasteHTML(this Range range, string html)
{
    Clipboard.SetData(
      "HTML Format",
      string.Format("Version:0.9\nStartHTML:80\nEndHTML:{0,8}\nStart" + "Fragment:80\nEndFragment:{0,8}\n", 80 + html.Length) + html + "<");
      range.Paste();
}
```

Sample use: `range.pasteHTML("a<b>b</b>c");`

Probably a bit more reliable way without using the clipboard is to save the HTML fragment in a file and use `InsertFile`. Something like:

```
public static void insertHTML(this Range range, string html) {
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "<html>" + html); // must start with certain tag to be detected as html: <html> or <body> or <table> ...
    range.InsertFile(path, ConfirmConversions: false);
    System.IO.File.Delete(path); }
```

Comment: Yeah, (+ 1 to you) using clipboard looks strange here

Comment: @R2D2 not sure what you mean .. but the clipboard is usually the least reliable way, because of the tiny chance of another application using it at the same time. I usually apply the formats programmatically for smaller ranges, or use templates with AutoText Building Blocks.

Comment: I am suing the clip board as the html I am loading is coming from a DB, Yes its bad I know. I am saying that the code needs to be marked as a Single thread to access the Clipboard

Comment: For the `insertHTML` solution, in the context of Outlook interop, don't forget to set `Attachment: false` so the HTML file will not be added as attachment!

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of tricky to add the html in a word document. The best way is creating a temporary file and than insert this file to selected range of the word. The trick is to leverage the ***InsertFile*** function of the ***Range***.  This allows us to insert arbitrary HTML strings by first saving them as files to a temporary location on disk.

> The only trick is that ***< html/>*** must be the root element of the
>   document.

I use something like this at one of my project.

```
   private static string HtmlHeader => "<html lang='en' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'><head><meta charset='utf-8' /></ head >{0}</html>";
   public static string GenerateTemporaryHtmlFile(Range range,string htmlContent)
    {
        string path = Path.GetTempFileName();
        File.WriteAllText(path, string.Format(HtmlHeader , htmlContent));
        range.InsertFile(FileName: tmpFilePath, ConfirmConversions: false);
        return path;
    }
```

it is important to adding

> charset='utf-8'

to head of html file other wise you may see unexpected characters at your word document after you insert file.

Comment: In the context of Outlook interop, don't forget to set `Attachment: false` so the HTML file will not be added as attachment!

Answer (score 0):

Just build a temporary html file with your html content and insert it like below.

```
// 1- Sample HTML Text
var Html = @"<h1>Sample Title</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor <b>his sonet</b> simul</p>";

// 2- Write temporary html file
var HtmlTempPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{Path.GetRandomFileName()}.html");
File.WriteAllText(HtmlTempPath, $"<html>{Html}</html>");

// 3- Insert html file to word
ContentControl ContentCtrl = Document.ContentControls.Add(WdContentControlType.wdContentControlRichText, Missing);
ContentCtrl.Range.InsertFile(HtmlTempPath, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing);
```

Comment: In the context of Outlook interop, don't forget to set `Attachment: false` so the HTML file will not be added as attachment!