# retrieve html content from database and parse to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

How do i parse html content stored in database in web form application? 
For instance: I have a column in table that stores the content like this:

```
<b>Hello</b><i>World</i>
```

I need to retrieve the content and save to word document.
So, how can i get the string text equivalent to:  **Hello** *World*

Comment: What have you done so far? you can use [HTML Renderer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) for the same.

Comment: i tried html agility pack. but it seems like it works while loading from a site with a url like this: var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url); This way it returns a HtmlDocument object.

Comment: check if the below stack overflow post helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363993/adding-html-text-to-word-using-interop

Comment: hi kalyana unfortunately the solution in the link only works with office interop. I am unable to use that.

Answer (score 0):

f the string is encoded in your database, then you need to call WebUtility.HtmlDecode:

```
@Html.Raw(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(someString))
```

Comment: Hi will this work with Web forms? I am not using mvc.

Comment: How about reference this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314951/how-to-render-encoded-tags-as-proper-html-rather-than-text